# Strange Issue! Red light coming out from Headset jack

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, 10.10, 12.04, headset

It is a very strange issue. This issue exists since I use ubuntu. In ubuntu `10.10`,`11.04`, `11.10` and even in the latest beta of `12.04` has this issue. The jack has red light light coming out. Although all seems to work fine but I am afraid if there is issue with my lappy. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: What kind of laptop do you have?

Comment: What is the relation between headfone jacket and ubuntu :oo

Comment: David Oneill: I have a Lenovo Ideapad Y550. It has core 2 duo 2.20 Ghz, 4 gb ram and 1 gb nvidia graphic.

Comment: Hint - when responding to a comment, put @ infront my my name (like `@DavidOneill` ) so it will automatically notify me.

Comment: ok! Do you know how to solve the above problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ok. It's for the optical audio output for HD quality.
Possible Solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/37971/optical-audio-jack-always-on-macbook-pro-5-2-natty

Comment: Can you please clearly clarify it?

Comment: This is normal, because ubuntu turns on your optical output by default. If you have an optical cable for your external amplifier, then you could enjoy the 5.1 lossless audio quality.

Comment: I had the same problem with one user in my dormitory, and it means no harm to you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any personal experience with Ideapads.

That being said, it can only be one of a few things:

1. Something's on fire.  Presumably you'd be able to tell if this were the case - it won't be a steady glow, you'd smell smoke, etc.
2. There is an LED designed to shine out of the the headphone jack.
3. There is an LED from somewhere else that happens to be shining out there.

If it were #2, I presume the documentation (for the laptop) would mention this somewhere.  If you take your computer apart, you might be able to find the LED that's shining through and see where it's plugged in.  It seems unlikely to me that you'd be able to do anything about it without either unplugging the offending LED or turning off whatever system is running it.

Comment: I have Windows 7 installed as a dual boot but I have no issue with it. It just appears in ubuntu. My headset works fine through..

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to think that you have an optical/digital audio output as well as an analogue from there.

I have the same thing here with an old laptop.

Have a look for S/PDIF in the manual or on the laptop.

Nothing to worry about.

Comment: I have a microphone jack and the headset jack is just on the left side of it...

Answer (score 0):

this happens on my ideacentre, Its a driver issue, as soon as i load windows 7, The light acts as normall, The light shouldnt be on constantly, Its malfunctioning because of a driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

My Y550 Ideapad was reconditioned about 3 years ago, and strangely had an
electrical fire in the laptop's hinge as I opened it to turn it on. It was
plunged into it's A/C charger as I had just used it the day before this
happened Saturday 04/13/2013. I think if the guy's laptop powered on and
didn't smell like burnt metal, you already answered his problem. But, if
it did smell of burnt metal or blown fuse, he would not be able to power
it back on, like my problem here.